# Extra outputs in a program to when using method overloading

Tags: java

I am making a program in which there are two methods of the same name using method overloading, specifics:-

1st method:- Name-getDurationString
             Parameters-minutes(check if >=0) and second(check >=0 and 
                                                                  <=59)
             if TRUE, convert minutes and seconds into their equivalent 
             hours, minutes and seconds and return a string in a format 
             "XX"h "YY"m "ZZ"s.

if FALSE, return a string "invalid value"

2nd method:- Name-getDurationString
             Parameters-seconds(check if >=0)
             if TRUE, convert seconds into their equivalent 
             minutes and seconds and return a string in a format 
             "YY"m "ZZ"s. Also, call the 1st method with the corrected 
             minutes and seconds.

if FALSE, return a string "invalid value"

Call both the methods from the main method.

Problem:- When running the code, instead of getting 3 outputs, I get 5.

```
public class MinutesAndSeconds {

public static void main(String[] args){
    getDurationString(120,58);
    getDurationString((7200));
}

public static  String getDurationString(int minutes,int seconds){
    if(minutes>=0 && seconds>=0 && seconds<=59){
        int hours=minutes/60;
        int remaingMinutes=(minutes%60);
        String i = hours + " h " + remaingMinutes + " m " + seconds +" s";
        System.out.println(i);
        return i;
    }
    else return "invalid value";

}

// 2nd method(overloading)
public static  String getDurationString(int seconds){
    if(seconds>=0){
        int correctedMinutes=(seconds/60);
        int correctedSeconds=seconds%60;
        String i = correctedMinutes + " m " + correctedSeconds + " s";
        System.out.println(i+"\n"+getDurationString(correctedMinutes,correctedSeconds));

        return (i+"\n"+getDurationString(correctedMinutes,correctedSeconds));
    }
    else return "invalid value";

}
```

}

Expected:-
**

- 2 h 0 m 58 s
- 120 m 0 s
- 2 h 0 m 0 s

**

Actual:-

- 2 h 0 m 58 s
- 2 h 0 m 0 s
- 120 m 0 s
- 2 h 0 m 0 s
- 2 h 0 m 0 s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in these lines:

```
System.out.println(i+"\n"+getDurationString(correctedMinutes,correctedSeconds));

return (i+"\n"+getDurationString(correctedMinutes,correctedSeconds));
```

`getDurationString()` is called in each one.

To get the same effect without multiple calls, save the value returned and print it later:

```
String result = getDurationString(correctedMinutes,correctedSeconds);
System.out.println(i+"\n"+result);
return i+"\n"+result;
```

Which also improves readability.

Comment: It works when I remove the print statements in the 1st and 2nd methods and print them via the main method, i.e:-                                                                  1)removing System.out.println(i); in the first method                                  
2)removing System.out.println(i+"\n"+getDurationString(correctedMinutes,correctedSeconds)); from 2nd method.                                                                                                            3)Running  System.out.println(getDurationString(120,58)+"\n"+getDurationString(7200));    in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem in this code is it brakes [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle); you have to split the calculation task and output task. In this case, you will never get unexpected side-effects. Look at the snippet below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getDurationString(120, 58)); // 02h 00m 58s
    System.out.println(getDurationString(7200));    // 02h 00m 00s
}

public static String getDurationString(int minutes, int seconds) {
    if (minutes >= 0 && seconds >= 0 && seconds <= 59)
        return getDurationString(minutes * 60 + seconds);
    return "invalid value";
}

public static String getDurationString(int seconds) {
    if (seconds < 0)
        return "invalid value";

    int hours = seconds / 3600;
    int minutes = seconds % 3600 / 60;
    seconds = seconds % 3600 % 60;

    return String.format("%02dh %02dm %02ds", hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```